# Python.net and DLLs

Tags: c#, python, .net, dll, python.net

I want to call a .Net dll using Python.net. Essentially what I want to do is operate a hardware device that comes with some dlls and sample C# code for operating it.

The sample of C# code I want to reimplement in python is:

```
    string[] strDeviceKeys = null;
    CmdLib8742 cmdLib = new CmdLib8742 (true, 5000, ref strDeviceKeys);
```

CmdLib8742 comes from a .net dll.

python.net *seems* to be installed correctly.

I can do this in python:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('CmdLib')
import NewFocus.Picomotor
cl = NewFocus.Picomotor.CmdLib8742()
```

That runs without error, but obviously doesn't seem to actually connect to the device.

It seems like I need to convert the python types to types that are understood by C#, so I probably have to replace `true` with `System.Boolean(True)`. But it's not clear to me how I pass this `ref strDeviceKeys`. I'm guessing this is passing a reference to the array of strings, but I don't know how to do that in python. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: No, I'm using cpython because I really only need to do this one thing with the .net dlls. I'm trying to use Python.net

Comment: There is an open issue about this: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/226

Answer (score -1):

You will probably need to look at [the `ctypes` library](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ctypes.html), which allows conversion between architecture-specific and Python values.